# Jquery , how append field value to id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Using

```
$("#input_text").appendTo("#somediv")
```

Appends the text field itself, I want to append it's value entered by user not itself.

Or if there a way to just use something like 
""+valueoffield+", bla bla".

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Append the value of a text field, not the text field itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to append the value of your input to `#somediv`, what you need to do is:

```
$( "#somediv" ).append( $( "#input_text" ).val() );
```

Comment: Ok that's proper. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#somediv").append($("#input_text").val());
```

If you would like to keep using `appendTo`. You have no option but to use it with some html tag when appending.

```
$('<span>' + $('#textbox').val() + '</span>').appendTo('#foo');
```

Comment: @BlessingThinker I corrected it. I will check how to do it using `appendTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div id="append">
```

js:

```
var append_photo='<img src="{@user_image}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail Image"style="width:125px; height:125px">';

$("#append").append(append_photo.replace("{@user_image}","image/profile_thumb.jpg"));
```